# Breakpoints in code::blocks not working

Tags: c++, gdb, codeblocks, mingw-w64

So, I have no idea why, but breakpoints in my code::blocks project are no longer working.  I'm using MinGW-W64 compiler and GDB.  I used to be able to use breakpoints, but now, for some reason, when I add them to my code they do absolutely nothing - code execution goes right past them without stopping.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: I had a similar experience last week with Visual Studio 10.0. Closing and restarting the IDE didn't help, but rebooting did. It seemed to me that using and crashing the stack view of procexp.exe somehow locked the debugger from setting breakpoints, which could only be reset by a reboot.

Comment: I just tried rebooting my computer, and nothing changed.  Breakpoints are still broken.

Answer (score 0):

You might be compiling your code in release mode. Try changing it to debug mode. Checkout http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks on how to turn on debugging symbols.

Comment: I'm compiling in debug mode, and I double checked to make sure -g and -pg are set.